# In which conditions the function is positive?

Tags: functions

$$
f(t)=\left[\frac{1-e^{-\alpha(t-\tau)}}{\alpha}+\frac{k\left[e^{-\alpha(t-\tau-1)}-e^\alpha+\alpha(t-\tau)\right]}{α^2} \right]\cdot c-\left[\frac{1-e^{-β(t-τ)}}{β}+\frac{k\left[e^{-β(t-τ-1)}-e^β+β(t-τ)\right]}{β^2} \right]\cdot d>0$$
where  $$0\le\tau\le t,  \ \ \ \alpha, \beta, c, d >0, \ \ \ k\ge0.$$
It is known that in a custom case, when $$k=0, \ \ \ c>d, \ \ \ \frac{c}{\alpha}>\frac{d}{\beta}$$
then $$f(t)>0.$$

Need to solve it in a more general way.